# Access fileEntry after dropping a file in a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, google-chrome-app, file-access

Is it possible to get a `fileEntry` object in Chrome Apps by opening a file via Drag'n'Drop? When I drop a file into my app I only get a `file` object which seems to be unrelated to the file system. I can't use that object to save the file after changing it.

I get the file like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
    file = event.dataTransfer.files[0]
});
```

### What I want to do

I'm developing a text editor and I want to add a feature to open a file by dragging it into my app.

As I said: I already get the content of the file, but I can't write changes back to the file since I need a `fileEntry` object in order to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I just found it while inspecting the `event` object. In the event object there's a function called `webkitGetAsEntry()` to get the `fileEntry` object. Here's the correct code:

```
document.body.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
    fileEntry = event.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry();
});
```

This is the object you can use to write changes back to the file system.

Code for reference:

```
// Of course this needs the "fileSystem" permission.

// Dropped files from the file system aren't writable by default.
// So we need to make it writable first.
chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(fileEntry, function (writableEntry) {
    writableEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
        // Here use `writer.write(blob)` to write changes to the file system.
        // Very important detail when you write files:
        // https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab_filesystem
        // look for the part that reads `if (!truncated)`
        // This also is very hard to find and causes an annoying error
        //   when you don't know how to correctly truncate files
        //   while writing content to the files...
    });
});
```